# Comparing char and constant char

Tags: c++, char

I'm new to c++ and programming I keep getting an error. I'm not able to compare char and constant chars. Any help will be appreciated.

```
char a;
cout << " presentation";
cout << "blablabla do you want to go left (type "l") or right (type "r")";
cin >> a;
if (a == "l")
{
  cout << "blablabla fall down it and brake your neck";
}
else
{
  cout << "blablabla";
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `;` all over the place in the front of lines?

Comment: Any possibility of code that compiles and demonstrates the problem? Even this web site has given up on highlighting the syntax

Answer (score 3):

`"1"` is a string literal and returns an object of type `const char[]` (array) not a `const char`

`'1'` is a char literal

Comment: Yes, which means `a == "1"` is testing the charcter in `a` against a pointer to the string, `"1"`.

Answer (score 3):

Also you have double-quotes inside the string you're trying to print. You need to escape these by writing `\"`.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing a char to an array of chars ("1" is an array of chars). The best bet is to probably change your if statement to:

```
if (a == '1')
```

that should solve your problem.

Also, you don't need the semicolons in front of the cout statements. ; should go at the end of the statement, not in front of it.

Also, quotes inside of char arrays should be escaped by putting a \ in front of them. ( \" )

Comment: thanks (it actually was an L I didn't notice it's similarity to 1)